# How can I subtract a dword (double word) form a qword (quad word)?

Tags: assembly

For example, I want to compute `a - b` , where `a` is a `qword` and `b` is a `dword`. How can I do this? Can I simply put `a` into `edx:eax` and subtract `b` from `eax`?

Comment: Look at compiler output for a function that does what you want.  You'll see it zero-extend or sign-extend depending on the signedness of the variable.  (With instructions that depend on the target architecture: in x86-64 you can simply `movzx rax, edi` to zero-extend to 64 bits.

Comment: Let a = edx;eax, b = ebx, then you can use `sub eax,ebx` `sbb edx,0`, using the carry bit as a borrow bit from the subtract.